# Running Symfony App Console From any Folder

Tags: php, magento, symfony, console

When I install a new Symfony application, either via composer or by downloading it directly, it ships with a command line `console` application.  I can run this application with the following command

```
$ php app/console help
```

In other systems that have developer command line applications, (Drupal's `drush`, Magento's `n98-magerun`, etc.), the application is capable of figuring out where the root folder is when you're deep in the file hierarchy, and you can run the application from anywhere

```
$ cd some/drupal/path
$ drush                   //still works!
```

To do something similar with Symfony's `app/console`, you need to construct this path yourself

```
$ cd some/symfony/path
$ php ../../../app/console
```

And even this may not work if the command relies on the PHP working directory being the root directory.

Is there a standard/well-supported way to get the "run from any folder" behavior of other CLI applications with Symfony's `app/console`?

Answer (score 2):

I use following console script for this purpose:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
function fileLocator($file =null, $maxDepth = 10, $currentDir = ".")
{
    if(empty($file)){
        return false;
    }elseif(file_exists($currentDir . "/$file")){
        return $currentDir;
    }elseif(--$maxDepth){
        return fileLocator($file, $maxDepth, $currentDir . "/..");
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

$projectDir = fileLocator('app', 10, getcwd());

if($projectDir){
    $projectDir = realpath($projectDir);
    if(substr($projectDir, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR){
        $projectDir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
    }

    $appDir = $projectDir . 'app';  
}else {
 die('You are not in symfony project');
}

// if you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

set_time_limit(0);

require_once $appDir.'/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once $appDir.'/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

### **For *nix users**

Create **console** file with this code. put it in your global path of your choice(like `/usr/local/bin/`) 
give it executable permission

> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/console

you are ready to go. You can run console from within any directory of a symfony2 project.

### **For windows users:**

Assuming you have your php path in path variable so you was able to execute console like `php app/console`.

create a `console.php` file with the same code. create a `console.bat` file with the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "%~dp0sf.php" %*
```

copy both `console.php` and `console.bat` file in your php directory. Now you are ready to go.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a symlink

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/app/console /usr/local/bin/console
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/console
```

then you can run `sudo console help`

Comment: Thanks! That'd probably be better is ~/bin — also, why the sudo?

Comment: This could be a dangerous approach when you have more than one symfony project. Imagine you have this symlink in place for project A.  Later, you are in project B and out of habit type: console doctrine:schema:drop.  You just dropped the db in project A!

Comment: The sudo because he linked into `/usr/local`. However, you want to run this as the user that owns the tree to avoid creating permission problems. The `/tmp/magento`issue is one you should be familiar with, that has this as root cause.

Comment: I had to update the `bin/console` file with absolute path, instead of `dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php'` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution implemented as a Bash script, so suitable under Linux/Mac or Cygwin's bash prompt under Windows. It should work fine even if you swap regularly between projects, as it doesn't rely on environment variables.

Make a script with the following contents, make it executable (using chmod a+x) and then put it in your path:

```
#!/bin/sh

 while [[ "`pwd`" != "/" ]]; do
    app_dir=`find \`pwd\`/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'app'`
    if [ -f "$app_dir/console" ]; then
      php $app_dir/console $@
      break
    fi

    cd ..
  done
```

Then just use it anywhere within your Symfony project, and use it like you would use "php app/console". It doesn't depend on any environment variables - all it does is recursively look at parent folders from where you're located, looking for app/console, and then runs it with any and all the parameters you pass to it (that's what the $@ symbol is for).

Answer (score 0):

I created a Bundle for this to resolve. It is currently only a bash/fish script, which creates something like a virtual environment:

```
$ composer require sk/symfony-venv
// [...] wait for install
$ . vendor/bin/activate
(project) $ console
```

On https://github.com/skroczek/symfony-venv you can read more. Feedback is welcome. :)